# How to prevent Session Hijacking in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am creating login app using ExpressJS. I want my session id to be renewed every time user request to the url in order to protect Session Hijacking. It works easily and perfectly in PHP. But in NodeJs i am having this trouble. I have googled around but didn't find any solution alike it. Here are some pics.
Express-Session (req.sesison.regenerate) function generating a new  session ID but it is logging out the user after regenerating new ID and also it is regenerating the new Session ID after 30 to 40 seconds not on every request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHUbB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeOtj.png)

Comment: Please do not include images of code. Instead, add the code to the post itself, ideally creating a Minimal Working Example (MWE) to help others debug your problem.

Comment: I cannot see Edit Question option.